# Camel Producer Template to Send Bulk/Multiple message

Tags: apache-camel

In my camel project, i need to send some message to a gateway (which will receive it as a JMS message).

In my camel project, my code is something like below:

```
@Produce(uri = "xxx")
private ProducerTemplate template;

@Override
public void sendToQueue(String textMessage, Map<String, String> properties) {
    template.sendBodyAndHeaders(textMessage, properties);
}
```

I just wondering how should I sent bulk messages.

Because in my camel project, a schedular will run every day and collect the data(around 1000) ---> Queue ---> File System as 1000 files.

Your assistance herein is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid JMS doesn't support to send bulk messages and  template sendBodyAndHeaders meothd doesn't support to send the bulk messages either.